# Expanding an accordion within an element that becomes active - bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm creating a ticket select panel using bootstrap framework. Within the panel we have "ticket name", if you click anywhere within the panel the input/radio button becomes active.

My problem is that I have a field within that serves as an "info" button, this expands information about the ticket using bootstraps accordion component. When clicking the info button from another ticket that ticket/input/radio button becomes active. Ideally I would like to se the info from another ticket without actually activating/selecting the ticket. So I need to exclude the button from making the ticket active.

Link to my demo - https://7bfcde86fc7f3304fcc6b50556a41b7e2907d0fd.googledrive.com/host/0B8UWGEiox1HOV0pnVTdsQXJpemM/test.html (you may need to load unsafe scripts for demo to work fully - Google drive security)

```
<div class="row ticket-selector">
    <label class="no-style">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="row pt-xs-15 pb-xs-15">
                <div class="col-xs-1 text-center font-xs-18 select-box">
                    <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="option1" class="mt-xs-10"> <span class="glyphicons ok_2"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-7 ticket-name">
                     <h4 class="font-xs-16 m-xs-0 mb-xs-5 mb-sm-0 mb-lg-5">Ticket Name <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#ticket-panel" href="#collapseOne" class="tickets-more"><span class="halflings info-sign orange"></span></a></h4>

                    <p class="mb-xs-0 font-sm-13 font-lg-14">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consec tetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2 text-center text-center font-xs-16 price">
                    <p class="mt-xs-10">&pound;123</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2 text-center font-xs-16 price">
                    <p class="mt-xs-10">&pound;123</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse pt-xs-10">
                        <p>Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et.</p>
                        <p>Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Please make a jsfiddle.net or a bootply.com demo rather than asking people to unblock to access it on GDrive

Comment: Yer, I did try a bootply but could not get the same demo to work